# How to copy/paste an image to another image with Konva.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

I'm building a game similar to Tetris, but with blocks that move smoothly (pixel by pixel).
At the moment I create a separate Konva `Image` object for each new block:

```
let block = new Konva.Image({
            x: 200,
            y: 0,
            transformsEnabled: 'position',
            listening: false,
            image: images.tiles,
            crop: {
              x: colorindex * 128,
              y: shapeindex * 128,
              width: 128,
              height: 128
            },
            width: 128,
            height: 128,
            colorindex: colorindex,
            shapeindex: shapeindex,
            falling: true,
            fallingspeed: 1, 
          });

that.blocks.push(block);
that.blocklayer.add(block);
```

With a lots of blocks on the screen I notice a slight slowdown in the animations.

Now I want to try and put all fixed blocks into 1 big Image object to see if this is faster.

Is it possible with Konva to copy a part of an image to another image ?

Comment: Can I check - you intend to put the 'landed' shapes into the fixed image and then you have only to be concerned with moving the current 'falling' shape ?

Comment: That's right. Since the landed blocks don't have to move anymore, they could be on 1 big image, so I need some kind of bitmap copying to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to just move several blocks into a group, and then just cache it:

```
group.cache();
```

Demo: https://konvajs.org/docs/performance/Shape_Caching.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into in. I didn't really understand the cache function in Konva.

Comment: @lavrton would a layer solution also be viable here - so split the canvas into two layers having one for the landed blocks and one for the moving block. Each time the moving block takes a step refresh its layer, and then when it lands in the game, transfer it to the landed layer and refresh that once.  The landed layer would have to do a significant refresh/redraw but only once when the shape landed thereby meaning the moving block refreshes work only on a single shape.